# Why is Pycairo not drawing any paths?

Tags: python, svg, pycairo

I'm working on a project to use midi input to generate svgs for my plotter to draw. Cairo was working fine up until recently, however, now it doesn't draw any paths on the surface. I do not think I changed anything that would have affected this, but I'm new to coding and this is the first project I'm doing to help me learn. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

def drawLine(params):

```
moveTo_X = params["moveTo_X"]
moveTo_Y = params["moveTo_Y"]
pointX, pointY = pointXY(params)

surface = cairo.SVGSurface(f"/Users/chrishedden/globalData/midi_svgs/midi_{i}.svg", width, height)
context = cairo.Context(surface)
context.scale(width, height)

context.move_to(moveTo_X, moveTo_Y)
context.line_to(pointX + offset, pointY + offset)
print(str(pointX + offset) + ' ' + str(pointY + offset))
context.stroke
surface.finish()
```

Comment: context.stroke() rather than what you have perhaps

Comment: For the future, you can track your changes with a tool like git, to see what exactly changed.